# How to use custom scoring function in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, parameters

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import PredefinedSplit
from sklearn.base import clone
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from mlxtend.evaluate import bias_variance_decomp
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
```

Below is custom_iterator. In each cross validation iteration, it will do train test split, and output current estimator with set parameter too.

```
knn = KNeighborsRegressor()
X_train_len = int(round(len(X_train_knn)*0.8,0))
X_test_len = len(X_train_knn)-X_train_len
test_fold = np.hstack([-1 * np.ones(X_train_len), np.zeros(X_test_len)])
ps = PredefinedSplit(test_fold)
def custom_iterator(X_train_knn, Y_train_ar, estimator, ps=ps):
    for train_index, test_index in ps.split():
        X_train_fold, X_test_fold = X_train_knn[train_index], X_train_knn[test_index]
        y_train_fold, y_test_fold = Y_train_ar[train_index], Y_train_ar[test_index]
        estimator1= clone(estimator)
        yield X_train_fold, X_test_fold, y_train_fold, y_test_fold, estimator1
iterator = custom_iterator(X_train_knn, Y_train_ar, estimator=knn, ps=ps )
```

my custom scoring function:

```
 `def custom_loss_func(y_true, y_pred,estimator1, X_train_fold, X_test_fold, y_train_fold, y_test_fold):
   avg_expected_loss, avg_bias, avg_var = bias_variance_decomp(
   estimator1, X_train_fold, y_train_fold, X_test_fold, y_test_fold, 
   loss='mse',
   random_seed=0)
   return avg_expected_loss
  score = make_scorer(custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=False).set_score_request(estimator1=True, 
  X_train_fold=True, X_test_fold=True, y_train_fold=True, y_test_fold=True)`
```

my GridSearchCV, uses multiple scorer in scoring_metrics, refits by score function.
**the problem now is how to pass [X_train_fold, X_test_fold, y_train_fold, y_test_fold, estimator1] into 'score'? (I tried set_score_request to accept these, but how to pass them in each iteration? is it by Metadata Routing?)**

```
`knn = KNeighborsRegressor()
param_grid = dict(n_neighbors=np.arange(1,21,1),weights= ['uniform',             
'distance'],p= np.arange(1,4,1))
scoring_metrics =    {'neg_root_mean_squared_error':'neg_root_mean_squared_error',   
 'r2':'r2','score_func': score}

grid = GridSearchCV(knn, param_grid, cv=custom_iterator,     
scoring=scoring_metrics, refit=score, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the documentation of https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html shows

```
**kwargs additional arguments

    Additional parameters to be passed to score_func.
```

which means that

```py
  score = make_scorer(custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=False).set_score_request(estimator1=True, 
  X_train_fold=True, X_test_fold=True, y_train_fold=True, y_test_fold=True)`
```

should be

```
  score = make_scorer(custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=False, estimator1=True, 
  X_train_fold=True, X_test_fold=True, y_train_fold=True, y_test_fold=True)`
```

where the extra parameters (on top of `y` and `y_pred`) to your custom scoring function are passed directly to `make_scorer`.

Comment: thanks, but how to pass these of current iteration: \n
estimator to estimator1
X_train  to X_train_fold
X_test to X_test_fold
y_train to y_train_fold
y_test to y_test_fold

Comment: I don't think this is supported by sklearn API you may need to superseed the GridSearchCV class with your own logic.